# class with bit field - function definition does not declare parameters

Tags: c++

```
class A
{
    static const int x=3;
    char array[x]   :24;
};
```

> error: function definition does not declare parameters
>        char array[x]   :24;

What does this error mean and why I'm getting it?

Comment: _"What does this error mean"_ That you have invalid syntax. _"why I'm getting it?"_ Because that's not a valid syntax for a bitfield union.

Comment: why not just int x = 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means you declare an illegal member. Plainly put at [[class.bit/]3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.bit#3):

> A bit-field shall not be a static member. A bit-field shall have
>   integral or enumeration type ([basic.fundamental]).

Which refers you to the fundamental types section to clarify what an integral or enumeration type is. An array is not one of those. And the `[x]` in the member declarator tries to make it into one.

The error message text itself could be better phrased however.